# Dell XPS 15 9570 with Ubuntu 19.04 synaptics touchpad problem

Tags: 19.04, synaptics, xps

There is an article in dell.com about how to fix the touchpad: https://www.dell.com/support/article/ca/en/cabsdt1/sln308258/precision-xps-ubuntu-general-touchpad-mouse-issue-fix?lang=en
However it looks like it only works for Ubuntu 16.04. There is not linux-generic-hwe-19.04 published yet. 
The point from which I could start fixing the touchpad is:
sudo gedit /usr/share/x11/xorg.conf.d/*synaptics-quirks.conf
But I don have a dirctory /usr/share/x11 in my system. So there is no way for me to "Disable generic Synaptics device" as the article mentions.

Could somebody please point me to what I am missing to have the /usr/share/x11 and the configurations files under it to try to follow those instructions.

Thanks

Update:
I had issued the two commands yesterday:

```
1986  sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
1987  sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

But I did not restart so I was still seeing the synaptics driver when I did a: "xinput list" command

But today it does not show up with "xinput list". I think I rebooted since yesterday.

```
 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
Wacom HID 488E Pen stylus                   id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Wacom HID 488E Finger                       id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
SYNA2393:00 06CB:7A13 Touchpad              id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Wacom HID 488E Pen eraser                   id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

I also don see it when i try to remove it with: "sudo apt-get remove synaptic" or "sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics" I get:
"0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 19.04 should default to using the more modern xinput drivers rather than the synaptics drivers. If you upgraded from an older version of Ubuntu, you may still be using the synaptics drivers.

To move to the xinput drivers, remove `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and make sure `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` is installed.

Comment: Thank for you suggestion I check today both package and one is removed and the other is installed. So I think that is equivalent to what the Dell link was advising.

Comment: @Fabio, no it isn't. In the Dell link, one keeps working with synaptics.

Comment: Still having trouble, installed ubuntu 19 fresh without upgrade from 18